# Trying to Understand a .htaccess File

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently servicing a website and I was given FTP access to the domain. I found a `.htaccess` file in there with the following:

```
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName thecathedrallagos.org

### BEGIN Z-PUSH REWRITE ###
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync$ /MobileEmailPush/index.php
### END Z-PUSH REWRITE #####
```

Please what does this mean? What is being rewritten? Any help in explaining would be appreciated as I know little or none about the rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing being rewritten is that `/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync` will be rewritten to actually serve `/MobileEmailPush/index.php`.

For the rest please refer to the [Apache Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/) where a search for `IndexIgnore`, `Limit`, `order`, `allow`, `deny` or `AuthName` will explain what the rest is doing.

Since the file is using the old `order/allow/deny` format you may in fact want the [documentation for Apache 2.2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/) or to review the documentation on [upgrading from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) paying particular attention to the [section on access](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access).

Comment: Thanks alot @SuperDuperApps